# What is the difference between v-model and .sync when used on a custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

I don't understand the difference between v-model and .sync used on a component.

```
<my-component v-model="myVar">
```

V-model is a shorthand for binding a variable (myVar) to the component property 'value' and listening to the 'input' event emitted from the component to update the variable 'myVar'.

```
<my-component v-bind:prop1.sync="myVar">
```

.sync is a shorthand for binding a variable (myVar) to a component property ('prop1' in this case) and listening to the 'update:prop1' event emitted from the component to update the variable 'myVar'.

I know that by default v-model only works with the 'value' property and the 'input' event but even that can be customized using the 'model' option in the component.

Would be nice if anybody could explain the difference to me or when to use what.

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2pcg0oxf/2/) where I used the same component in three different ways:
1) manual binding + event listening
2) .sync
3) v-model

Answer (score 43):

For Vue.js 2 both pretty much do the same thing - enable two-way binding, although `.sync` is more versatile. It was added after v-model was added for components. `.sync` allows to use v-model logic for more than one prop. Let's compare:

- [`.sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

```html
<comp
  :value.sync="username"
  :age.sync="userAge"
/>
```

expands to:

```html
<comp
  :value="username"
  :age="userAge"
  @update:value="val => username = val"
  @update:age="val => userAge = val"
/>
```

- [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

```html
<input v-model="userName1" />
<comp v-model="userName2" v-model:profile-name="profileName" />
```

expands to:

```html
<input
  :value="userName1"
  @input="event => userName1 = event.target.value"
/>

<comp
  :value="userName2"
  :profile-name="profileName"
  @update:value="val => userName2 = val"
  @update:profile-name="val => profileName = val"
/>
```

The differences as we can see are:

- the default prop name `v-model` always binds to property called `value`
- `.sync` allows you to use multiple props
- the event name emitted from component (`@update` for `.sync` and `@input` for `v-model`)

One very interesting feature of `.sync` is its special handling of objects. The `.sync` modifier when used on an object will set multiple props at once (more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier))

Which one to use? It is a standard pattern to use property `value` as the key  value carrier for a component. In this situation if you have `value` property and want to enable 2-way binding for it then use `v-model`. In all other cases use `.sync`

Comment: Wanted to add a point that you missed. We don't necessarily need to use the 'value' prop and the 'input' event. We can modify it - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-v-model-support-to-custom-vue-js-components

Comment: Do you think it makes sense for someone developing components for other develops to support both the `v-model` and `.sync` apis for their 'single editable prop' components?  i.e. emit both `input` and `update:value`?  I worry about emitting too many events, but also figure that won't be an issue

Comment: It says deprecated for me, see also: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-deprecated-v-bind-sync.html

Comment: @husayt, I think there´s a typo in the 2nd line of code: `@update:value="val => userName = val"`. In other words, the property that, when changed, triggers the update is `value` and not `name`.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't much difference, so much so that there is a plan to potentially merge them in Vue 3:

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/8

In cases where a component has a natural candidate for two-way binding you'd use `v-model`. So text inputs, checkboxes, etc. would all use `v-model`. Similarly it might make sense in the context of a component with a concept of selection. You could use `sync` instead but it isn't typically what other developers would be expecting.

In Vue 2 you can only have a single prop/event wired up to `v-model`. If you want two-way binding for multiple props/events then you'd have to use `sync`.

Vuetify contains several examples of components that use both `v-model` and `sync`. For example, `v-autocomplete`:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes

This uses `v-model` for the selected value but it also uses `sync` for `error` and `search-input`.